# Crawling data from external database

Tags: search, sql-server, bcs, crawl-external-content

I need to crawl data from SQL Server Database. For this, I created an external list using Business Connectivity Services. 
However, I encountered a limit on the number of requested rows: my table contains more than 2000 rows.

- How can I get around this problem?
- Is it possible to make the data requested by parts?
- Is there another better way to index data from the database?

**UPDATE**

I found that the limit on the number of returned rows does not affect the search crawler, it is able to successfully index all records from external content regardless of limits.

Comment: you can increase the throttle limits.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bcs/2010/02/16/bcs-powershell-introduction-and-throttle-management/)

Increasing throttle limits would degrade the query performance.

As advice, try to design your BDC models with different finders according to your business requirements and use them on your target external list over dedicated views. (Eg. Refine by quarter, Filter by the current user, ...)

Enjoy.